SwiftUI Text, changing the text with @State property causing whole view to re-render
I am facing a really strange issue and I have no clue how to solve this problem. There is a Text and a TabView in a VStack. Now the problem is, when I am trying to set the Text's text based on some @State property. SwiftUI refreshes all the views including the pages that are added in the TabView are also recreated. I am sharing an example code snippet that will help it to explain.
My Main View:
struct TestingView: View {
    
    @State private var someText: String = "Hello"
    @State private var page: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someText + " \(page)")
            
            TabView(selection: $page) {
                ViewOne()
                    .tag(0)
                
                ViewTwo()
                    .tag(1)
                
                ViewThree()
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

Tab view pages:
struct ViewOne: View {
    
    init() {
        print("View one init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("View one")
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    
    init() {
        print("View two init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("View two")
    }
}

struct ViewThree: View {
    
    init() {
        print("View three init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("View three")
    }
}

Now if you I swipe on the TabView it causes change on $page which eventually effects Text . When the text inside Text changes all the views are recreated.
My Questions:

What causes SwiftUI internally to behave like this?
How can I prevent unintentional redrawing of view?

I have tried making a separate view for the Text and bind the value from TestingView, but the result is same.

Did you think that the views' inits being called means that they are "redrawn"? That's not true, and that isn't something SwiftUI does "internally" - you are calling them in TestingView.body.

Building on @Sweeper's comment, profiling the app with Instruments shows that the body redraw count remains the same, but the number of Core Animation commits is slightly higher.

@Sweeper Why the init inside ViewOne, ViewTwo and ViewThree called?

In your TabView, you wrote ViewOne(). You do realise that is the syntax for calling ViewOne.init right?

If Text is not changed, init inside the TabView pages won't called.

So? I don't see your point. I really recommend watching Demystifying SwiftUI, by the way.

https://medium.com/@vladislavshkodich/mastering-swiftui-are-you-really-as-good-as-you-think-40a4953f7e88

ITGuy gave an excellent explanation in their answer. page changes so SwiftUI calls TestingView.body. In there, you call VStack.init, which runs the closure passed to it, so TabView.init gets called, which runs the closure passed to it, so all your tabs' inits get called.
Unlike UIViews or NSViews (which you might be familiar with), SwiftUI views are very lightweight, and calling a view's init does not do much at all. Each of your tabs has no instance properties, so it is like initialising an empty struct. It is similar to:
struct Empty { }
Empty() // surely you'd agree this does almost nothing

What you are returning in body is just a lightweight description for SwiftUI to create the actual views. SwiftUI inspects this description behind the scenes and figures out which views it needs to update. It does this by calling body. Notice that none of your tabs' bodys are ever called except for the first time (try adding a breakpoint to test this!). This shows that they are not updated. TestingView.body is called, because the Text needs updating.
If you want to avoid the tabs' inits being called, you can wrap the tabs into another View.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someText: String = "Hello"
    @State private var page: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someText + " \(page)")
            
            TabView(selection: $page) {
                Tabs()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct Tabs: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewOne()
            .tag(0)
        
        ViewTwo()
            .tag(1)
        
        ViewThree()
            .tag(2)
    }
}

Now, though Tabs.init will be called, ViewOne.init and the other tabs' inits will not be called, because Tabs.body will not be called when page changes.

SwiftUI works as follows:
Whenever the state of a view changes, this change is scheduled as an update task internally by SwiftUI on the main thread.
State changes are triggered by changes to State properties, Environment variables and objects, objectWillChange publishers or non-private property changes to Observable objects.
The SwiftUI layout task first creates a new instance of the view and then compares whether the state change requires a new layout process. Also keep in mind that views are value types.
If a new layout process is required, the old view instance is replaced by the new one, the state variables are transferred and the body property of the new instance is retrieved.
In your example, the state of TestingView is changed by changing the page state property. This causes a new layout process to be triggered during the next layout phase, i.e. the body property is called on TestingView.
This also calls the init methods of ViewOne, ViewTwo and ViewThree since that's what your body implementation does.
However, SwiftUI then recognizes through a comparison that these child views have not changed and does not call their layout method. As a result, the unnecessarily generated views are discarded.
Here are a few basic things you should understand and keep in mind about SwiftUI:

The init methods of views can be called very often and do not mean that a view is also re-layouted.
The init methods of views should be as lightweight as possible and must not change any state variables or state objects.
If you want to debug why the layout process of a view was called, you can insert the following code line in the body of your view:

let _ = Self._printChanges()


That is really a nice and helpful explanation. I confusion I still have is, in my example there is a Text that consumes page property. If I comment the Text, alone TabView will cause the pages init to call. But when there is some other view that consumes same property will cause the init to call.

I am confused with why TabView works fine alone which is still using page property?

@DaudMujib TabView is rather the exception than the rule in this case. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78948974/5133585

@DaudMujib The reason why the use of page in the body of TestingView always leads to an init call is relatively simple: the code of body is called as a whole and cannot be called only partially. So the moment TestingView.body is called, the content parameter of TabView is also automatically called.
The reason why TabView does not call its body when selection is changed is an internal implementation detail of TabView itself, which obviously does not bind selection to a SwiftUI view state. Otherwise changing selection would call the init methods of ViewOne/Two/Three.
